# Type of socket address from recvfrom() with AF_PACKET / PF_PACKET

Tags: c, linux, sockets

On two PC, I am opening an AF_PACKET / PF_PACKET socket, raw protocol.

> sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(PROTO_BULK))

(edit: PROTO_BULK is a dummy type, created by myself for this test. I do not expect it to be inferring with this problem, but I may be wrong.)

The first PC send a packet to the other the standard send() way, which is received on the other side with:

> recvfrom(sock, buffer, 1600, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &from, &fromlen);

My problem is now: what is the type of the data in "from"? Here is an exemple of what I am receiving:

> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f8 cd a1 00 58 1d a1 00 94 60

From the length and the content, it does not look like a "struct sockaddr" nor a "sockaddr_ll". Any idea?

I am actually looking for the interface the packet was received on. I could use the destination MAC from the packet and identify the interface from it, but it would not work with a broadcast packet.

I am running a recent Linux kernel (and I do not want to investigate in the kernel sources!).

**Edit:** My code was wrong. I did not initialized "fromlen" with "from" buffer size, so I supposed some spurious value was there and "recvfrom()" could not do its job correctly. Thanks to Ben Voigt for pointing me this bug with his comment below! Of course, I did not include this part of the faulty code in my question, as it was obvious there could be no mistake with such simple code...

With the correct paramter, I get a "struct sockaddr_ll" correctly filled, including the interface number I was looking for.

Comment: 1. What is the value of `fromlen`. 2. Have you actually tried to cast to `sockaddr_ll` and found out it contains invalid data?

Comment: To cnicutar: 1. fromlen is 18, as the dump shows. 2. Yes, it has no sense.

Comment: `struct sockaddr` isn't guaranteed to have portable layout, so please also include what the different fields are when the buffer is interpreted (via cast) as `struct sockaddr`, `struct sockaddr_pkt`, `struct sockaddr_ll`, etc.

Comment: What is `fromlen` before you call `recvfrom`?  The kernel can't make your address buffer bigger than it started out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am actually looking for the interface the packet was received on.

You should be using [`recvmsg`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg), which gives access to metadata such as the packet's destination address (useful for multihomed systems) and I think also the interface.

The sender address you're looking at now isn't going to tell you the interface.  It's good for sending a reply packet with `sendto` though.

Answer (score 1):

I took a glance at the kernel sources.  I do not claim to fully understand them, but...

Is PROTO_BULK 37984 (0x9460)?

If so, this is probably a "struct sockaddr_pkt".  (It has the right size, anyway.)  Although I am not sure what the other bytes mean.  If I am reading the code correctly, they should be the "name" of the interface on which the packet was received.  So I am probably reading the code incorrectly.

Comment: About PROTO_BULK, I will edit the original question. The "sockaddr_pkt" has the right size, but data is not matching. From the "man 7 packet" doc, it also says it is a relic from Linux 2.0.